# Вывод отработанного цикла

Tags: java

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n0 = 1, n1 = 1, n2;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            n2 = n0 + n1;
            n0 = n1;
            n1 = n2;
        }
        System.out.print(n2);
    }
}
```

Какой есть способ вывода на консоль последней итерации цикла? Т.е. нап-р если ввести число 5, то вывод должен быть 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Приведенный Вами код не скомпилируется, так как возможна ситуация, когда переменная `n2` не будет инициализирована, однако Вы пытаетесь вывести ее значение на консоль.

Возможно, Вам подойдет вариант с инициализацией этой переменной:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n0 = 1, n1 = 1, n2 = 0;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = in.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            n2 = n0 + n1;
            n0 = n1;
            n1 = n2;
        }
        System.out.print(n2);
    }
}
```

При `a == 5`, на консоль будет выведено значение `13`.